# How to create XML file from PHP array (using echo statments)?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, oracle

I am currently trying to create an XML file within PHP. I used PHP with an Oracle database to pull the data I want and validate it according to specific standards. Now I would like to be able to call upon the elements in my PHP array to create an XML file according to a certain schema. Is it possible to simply echo out the XML tags and then reference the array to fill in the values? Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 while($row=oci_fetch_array($array, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
            echo   '<batchContactList>
                        <contact contactID="xxxxxx" action="AddOrModify">
                        <contactField name="LAST NAME">'.$row["LAST NAME"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="FIRST NAME">'.$row["FIRST NAME"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="MIDDLE INITIAL">'.$row["MIDDLE INITIAL"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="COUNTRY">'.$row["COUNTRY"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 1"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 1"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 2"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 2"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 3"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 3"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 4"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 4"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 5"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 5"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 6"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 6"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 7"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 7"].'</contactField>
                        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 8"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 8"].'</contactField>';
    };
```

What I want this to do is echo out all of these XML tags/values while parsing through all of the results within my Oracle array. Instead, it is just echoing out all of the values without any tags. Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this in an easier way while still conforming with this XML schema?

Comment: initialize a string first, then build the xml string structure and concatenate it along the loop, then finally, just follow @user583576's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$test_array = array (
    'bar' => 'foo',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'another_array' => array (
        'baz' => 'bat',
    ),
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that I dont have a normal PHP array. It is being pulled from Oracle using the oci_fetch_array() method and pulling row by row. It also will not allow me to make it match my schema identically.

Comment: You are writing to a file, or you want to display the output as XML on a web page?

If a web page, page the tags get interpret/mangled by the browser, in which case perhaps you should wrap a "<pre> ... </pre>" tag around the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I found that the easiest (but possibly not the cleanest) way to accomplish what I needed to do was by making use the htmlspecialchars() method within PHP. Here is the code I ended up using to echo the XML code and get exactly the correct output I needed for anyone else who is trying to do the same thing:

```
echo    htmlspecialchars('<contact contactID="'.$row["UNIQUE ID"].'" action="AddOrModify">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="LastName">'.$row["LAST NAME"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="FirstName">'.$row["FIRST NAME"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="MiddleName">'.$row["MIDDLE INITIAL"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="Country">'.$row["COUNTRY"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 1"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 1"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 2"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 2"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 3"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 3"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 4"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 4"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 5"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 5"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 6"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 6"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 7"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 7"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 8"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 8"].'</contactField>')."<br><br>".


    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointList>')."<br>".

    htmlspecialchars('<contactPoint type="Voice">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPoint>')."<br><br>".

    htmlspecialchars('<contactPoint type="Voice">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE 2 LABEL"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 2 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 2"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 2"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPoint>')."<br><br>".

    htmlspecialchars('<contactPoint type="Email">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["EMAIL LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Address">'.$row["EMAIL 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPoint>')."<br><br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPointList>')."<br><br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contact>')."<br><br>";
```